Confusion understanding series/parallel relationship of mechanical components of a DC motor in Simulink Simscape
After watching this youtube video, I am trying to implement Simscape model of a DC motor in simulink - see snapshots below.
I understand from both photos that the electrical components' resistance and  inductance are in series with each other and the electromechanical converter, but I am confused by the series/parallel relationship of mechanical components, inertia, and rotational damper and their relationship with the electromechanical converter. According to my understanding of simscape, damper rotational electromechanical converter are in parallel with each other and this parallel combination is in series with inertia. But i am confused by the schematic diagram, is there same series parallel relationship like that in simscape?



One generally uses force as a voltage equivalent and current as a distance equivalent in mechanical models.  Springs physically in "series" behave like electrical elements in parallel (F for the F=kx relation is the same for both springs). Simulator blocks usually behave like gains rather than circuit connections so mixes of the two can certainly get confusing. Write out the equations for your model and verify they match the physics you desire.
